# Twitter REST v1 API - Tweepy -Python - Authentication

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a simple Python app with Tweepy to upload image to Twitter.
This feature is available only with V1 API.
The access to V1 API is possible either with Standalone App or with Elevated Privileges.

I did both of them but I constantly receive 403 Forbidden error.

Here is my simple code:

```
client_v1 = tweepy.API(auth=auth)
upload_file_media = client_v1.media_upload(
    filename="my_image.jpg"
)
```

This, I tried with all 3 possible authentication methods:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuth2AppHandler
auth = tweepy.OAuth2BearerHandler
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler
```

None of them worked.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 3411, in media_upload
    additional_owners=additional_owners, **kwargs
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 3455, in simple_upload
    upload_api=True, **kwargs
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 259, in request
    raise Forbidden(resp)
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
```

Any idea what could be the reason?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think I found a way of doing this. There is a setting "User authentication settings". Go there and activate Oauthv1. It is asking some callback URL and website URL. If you have commandline or batch job, these are unnecessary. Simply use 127.0.0.1 and localhost. Then it works. weird setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way of doing this.
There is a setting "User authentication settings". Go there and activate Oauthv1.
It is asking some callback URL and website URL. If you have commandline or batch job, these are unnecessary.
Simply use 127.0.0.1 and localhost. Then it works.
weird setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a new developer account then you will need Elevated access to access the v1.1 API. You will need to Use the OAuth1UserHandler with the v1.1 media upload API in order to upload media for an authorised user.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Elevated access with the Oauth1UserHandler. I tried all these.